# Dynamically Build UPDATE statement within INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I want to dynamically build an UPDATE statement within a trigger, so I need some help with the temp variables and length related functions and using the temporary variable to specify the field/updated values in the UPDATE statement:

```
stSQL as string
stSQL = ""

IF FieldA=<criteria> then
 stSQL = "FieldB = we_ci_db.dbo.ztblTest.FieldA"
endif

IF FieldG=<criteria> then
 if len(stSQL)>0 then stSQL=stSQL & " AND "
 stSQL = "FieldH = we_ci_db.dbo.ztblTest.FieldF"
else
 if len(stSQL)>0 then stSQL=stSQL & " AND "
 stSQL = "FieldH = we_ci_db.dbo.ztblTest.FieldG"
endif

UPDATE ztblTest
SET stSQL
WHERE TestID IN (SELECT DISTINCT TestID FROM inserted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me like you need to build up a string, use dynamic SQL, or have all of these `IF` conditionals. Two simple inline `CASE` expressions seem to do it:

```
UPDATE z
SET FieldB = CASE WHEN i.FieldA = <criteria> THEN i.FieldA ELSE i.FieldB END,
    FieldH = CASE WHEN i.FieldG = <criteria> THEN i.FieldF ELSE i.FieldG END
FROM dbo.ztblTest AS z
INNER JOIN inserted AS i
ON z.TestID = i.TestID;
```